# ffmpeg : How to set the number of frames per second (FPS)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am happy doing the following ffmpeg to extract a part of an original mp4 into a new one - ready for cross fading with a number of other mp4s, but input.mp4 is 25FPS and I need it to be 50.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/input.mp4" 
 -ss 8.620667 -to 221.74966666666649
 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/output.mp4"
```

I therefore figured I could add `-vframes 50` to adjust the FPS...

```
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/input.mp4" 
 -ss 8.620667 -to 221.74966666666649 -vframes 50
 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/output.mp4"
```

But the result (output.mp4) remains 25fps. I see no error messages in the cmd stdout - but it's obviously not worked.

How do I set the FPS on the output on this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - i think I've found the answer by adding `fps=50` to the -vf argument...

```
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/input.mp4" 
  -ss 8.620667 -to 221.74966666666649
  -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black,fps=50" "E:/output.mp4"
```